# Custom Configuration on mat dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am creating a project using angular and material. I am using the angular material dialogs in my application. I am opening dialogs almost from 10 screens, Now i want to add class on top of the dialogs but i don't want to write the code for all screens to add the class. I want to add class globally on mat dialog basis of some conditions

```
this.dialog.open(testcomponent, data);
```

Please suggest me any idea.

**I dont want to add on each component, i want to add globally on dailog container**

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add your custom class everytime you want to open your dialog.
Check the doc : https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig

```js
this.dialog.open(testcomponent, {
  data,
  panelClass: CONDITION ? 'class1' : 'class2'
});
```

Comment: I dont want to add on each component, i want to add globally on dailog container

Comment: Then you will have to implement your own dialog factory.

Comment: @Karan Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Yes, With creating the service and calling internal mat dialog

Answer (score 0):

You can add **panelClass** to you dialog [config](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig) and set style for this class globally:

```
this.dialog.open(testcomponent, {
  // ...
  panelClass: 'customClass'
    });
```

Comment: I dont want to add on each component, i want to add globally on dailog container

Comment: So, you can wrap you dialog:    .custom-wrapper >  mat-dialog-container {
        // styles
}